# SOLVED: AggregrateResult is not returning Value

Tags: apex, class, aggregate, aggregateresult

I am attempting to calculate the sum MRR of Assets related to an Account and add it to a field on the Opportunity object. The code doesn't show an error but does not return values when new Opportunities are created. This is a Trigger.isBefore class.

```
Map<Id,List<Opportunity>> qualifiedOpportunities = new Map<Id,List<Opportunity>>();
       for(Opportunity opp : opportunities)
       {
           if(opp.Type ==  'Past Due' && Trigger.isInsert)
           {
               if(! qualifiedOpportunities.containsKey(opp.Location__c) ) qualifiedOpportunities.put(opp.Location__c,new List<Opportunity>());
               //ADD TO QUALIFIED OPPS TO SET AMOUNT BEFORE PROCESSING
               qualifiedOpportunities.get(opp.Location__c).add(opp);
           }
       }

       for(AggregateResult a  : [SELECT SUM(Current_Price__c),Location__c FROM Asset WHERE Location__c IN :qualifiedOpportunities.keySet() AND Status = 'Active' GROUP BY Location__c])
       {
           for(Opportunity opp : qualifiedOpportunities.get((Id) a.get('Location__c')))
           {
               opp.Past_Due_MRR__c = (Decimal) a.get('expr0');
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Is `Location__c` non-null?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes, the `Location__c` field is a required field on the opportunity.

Comment: Which object is the trigger on? If its on opportunity then you won't get opportunity ids in a before trigger, you maye have to write trigger against after insert event. Do you see field from Salesforce UI (to be sure that fls is enabled for the fields)?

Comment: @Raul The fls was the issue. I should have double-checked that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was not thorough and did not double-check the field level security in my sandbox. This was root of the issue.